# JQuery/AJAX with JSON - $GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'] is null?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm struggling with something that should be very simple. I've spent hours looking for a solution on the web and have checked out the jQuery docs.

I'm trying to post a simple request to my server sending through a json string.
I have tried escaping the json, encodeURIcomponent, etc. I'm sure it's simple and I'll have a bruise for slapping myself soon, but here it goes:

Here is the Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#mybutton").click(function(e) {
submitMyRequest();  
});
});


function submitMyRequest()
{

var json = [{"id":"1", "area":"south"}, {"id":"2", "area":"north"},{"id":"3", "name":"east"},{"id":"1", "name":"west"}];

 jQuery.ajax({
     url: "test_server.php",
     type: "POST",
     data: {areas: json },
     dataType: "json",
     beforeSend: function(x) {
         if (x && x.overrideMimeType) {
             x.overrideMimeType("application/j-son;charset=UTF-8");
         }
     },
     success: function(result) {
     alert(result);
     }
 });
}
```

Here is the server code:

```
print_r(json_decode($GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'],true));
```

The result I keep getting is an alert that says:

```
null
```

Comment: I've also tried using application/json instead of application/j-son but that didn't help

Comment: You more than likely don't need to decode JSON on your server if you are setting up the POST with `dataType: "json"`. Try a simple `var_dump($_POST);` in test_server.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
var json = '[{"id":"1", "area":"south"}, {"id":"2", "area":"north"},{"id":"3", "name":"east"},{"id":"1", "name":"west"}]';
```

And on your server side:

```
print_r(json_decode($_POST['areas'],true));
```

Comment: I tried this, but now the request fails (nothing is returned). I checked this by adding    success: function(result) { alert('fail'); }

Comment: @NEW2WEB The problem is most likely that setting `dataType: "json"` result in the function expecting a JSON string as a return value. Try setting it to `text`.

Comment: That did it! (changing it to 'text' instead of 'json') I swear I took most of the above code (including the offending code) from an earlier accepted solution on stackoverflow. Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.always-populate-raw-post-data), `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` is populated only with unrecognized MIME type of the data. To overcome this you can set the `always_populate_raw_post_data` ini value to true or use the preferred method for accessing the raw POST data, reading from `php://input`

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

Also it doesn't look like you're sending json to the server, try this

```
data: JSON.strinify({areas: json }),
```